# Flutter - How to get progress of a Loading Indicator?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to get the value of progress being made from a dependency - https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_animation_progress_bar

```
void main() {
  runApp(
    Center(
        child: FAProgressBar(
      currentValue: 80,
      displayText: '%',
    )),
  );
}
```

I need to provide it with a `semanticValue` like `CircularProgressIndicator` has but how do I fetch the value if I am calling the `ProgressBar` from a `FutureBuilder`?